# Quanto tempo uma sinalização pode ficar pendente?

Tags: debate, suporte, sinalização

Tenho uma dúvida sobre as filas de análise e vou deixar um exemplo para ver se podem esclarecê-la.

Sinalizei uma pergunta já há dois dias. A minha questão é a seguinte, ela neste momento ainda está por ser validada. Qual o motivo? Foi apenas por que ainda ninguém a avaliou nas filas de análise? Porque se fosse uma má sinalização, por norma, ela mostra como rejeitado, e se fosse uma boa sinalização, ela mostra como útil.

É possível que a sinalização posso ficar perdida para todo o "sempre"?

**Exemplo:**
[image: Print]

Comment: Que tipo de sinalização? A maioria nem fica muito tempo pendente, pois membros com certa reputação podem analisar e como são muitos já, acaba que as analises são rapidas. Se for de fechamento, ai é um problema pois a fila está meio congestionada, parece que poucos analisam, pois pra essa analise depende do conhecimento do analista sobre o tema do post.

Comment: @Articuno deve ser por esse motivo mesmo a sinalização e para fechar a pergunta.

Comment: Existem 5 status de sinalização, útil, rejeitado, disputado(fica aquele empasse, alguns falam que é útil, ou rejeitam), retirado(você cancelou a sinalização) e expirado, que é (acredito) a que você procura entender.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depende do tipo de sinalização. Se for algo que só moderadores podem avaliar ficará listado até que um moderador decida o que fazer. Geralmente é rápido, mas pode demorar dias, semanas, não digo meses porque depois disso se ninguém souber o que fazer provavelmente á para fazer nada.

Algumas sinalizações só são mostradas para os moderadores após 1 hora.

Sinalizações que não precisam de intervenção de moderadores não são mostradas para moderadores, elas entram em análise da comunidade e se não me engano ficam assim por até 30 dias.

Não há sinalizações pendentes há 2 dias, suas ou de outros usuários, todas foram processadas.

Comment: Pode não chegar a dois dias pois os valores são arredondados a dias mas tenho uma sinalização que mostra esse valor(2), como explicado pelo @Articuno fiquei a perceber um dos principais motivos para o atraso da verificação a minha sinalização.

Comment: Sinalização de fechar na prática se torna um início de processo de fechamento muito rápido.

Comment: mas é comum demorar assim tanto tempo então?

Comment: Repito: não há sinalização alguma pendente, não tem tanto tempo.

Comment: @Tmc Acho que você está falando de uma sinalização de fechamento. Essas não chegam aos moderadores, apenas levam a pergunta pra fila de análise. E, se for a pergunta que estou pensando, está lá na fila ainda, aguardando análises da comunidade.

Comment: Tal como já tinha referido pode ser os arredondamentos de valores mas mais uma vez também repito que tenho uma sinalização com 2 dias, já editei a pergunta onde é possível de ver isso. ATENÇÂO: não me quero estar a chatear com alguém muito menos  estar a ser casmurro

Comment: @bfavaretto ok, foi o que o articuno já tinha falado que está demorado a fila de análise de fecho, algo que eu já pode verificar e comfirmar.

Comment: Eu tenho uma pergunta que está como "Aguardando análise" desde o dia 02/09

Comment: @DenisRudneideSouza o motivo é o mesmo que comentei na pergunta mais acima, analise de fechamento demora porque nem todos tem conhecimento pra poder analisar com precisao determinadas perguntas, por isso pulam ou ignoram. Tem o fato tambem de muitos usuarios de alta reputação não visitarem essas filas mais tambem, eu mesmo sou um desses.

Comment: @Tmc Neste momento, a minha fila de fechamento mostra 49 perguntas. E olhar as perguntas nessa fila é algo chato e que toma bastante tempo. Além disso, não gosto de dar voto de fechamento sem ter certeza, e portanto tendo a pular os casos que versam sobre coisas que não sei julgar ou que por algum motivo não queira me envolver. E embora haja alguns truques para se escolher os itens que deseja-se avaliar na fila de fechamento, esse são bem limitados, e no geral você é obrigado a avaliar as questões na ordem que a fila te entrega elas.

Comment: @Tmc No caso dessa pergunta, eu acho que ela está um pouco ampla, mas não sei se ao ponto de merecer ser fechada. Me dá a entender que ainda assim é possível respondê-la sem maiores complicações.